# Remove magento2 admin grid all tabs

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform, tabs

I created on magento to admin grid module all working find . currently i have one tab i want remove this tab and form should display as full page

currently my module look like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching in Magento2 I found that by default magento2 team also create a form without tab, you can check the same in

`Stores > All Stores`

Open any `store` which you have in your webshop and you can find the same thing which you want, but still I am adding the screenshot :)

[image]

After digging into core I found that they have not created any `layout` `xml` file for this (at least I am not able to find it), this makes me more Interesting about this, so I checked the `controller` of this action and found some strange thing which I never used it before which is

```
$resultPage->addContent($resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit::class
            ));
```

It means they are adding directly content in `$resultPage` object. I would suggest you look into this `module-backend` of core. especially below files,

`\Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit`

`\Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Store`

`\Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Store\EditStore`

Just check this file I am sure that you can have something and from something you can build anything

**EDIT**

Found the same thing in `module-currency-symbol` from `Stores > Currency Rates`

you can check belwo files for this action

`adminhtml_system_currency_index.xml`

`\Magento\CurrencySymbol\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Currency\Index`